# Using ReactBootstrap components from ClojureScript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, clojurescript

I have this lein dependency:

```
[cljsjs/react-bootstrap "0.27.3-0"]
```

, and in cljs code am trying to refer to a React Bootstrap component like this:

```
(defn button [info]
  (js/ReactBootstrap.Nav (js->clj {:key (:id info)}) (:name info)))
```

The problem I am having is not so much with the code, but with the fact that the component (`ReactBootstrap.Nav`) is not being recognised. I get this error message in the browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactBootstrap is not defined
```

Apart from the lein dependency, what steps do I need to perform to get React Bootstrap components to be recognised from with ClojureScript?

*Edit* That was a silly mistake (above error message is due to absent or incorrect require). I have been getting quite a few error messages. For example:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: om_alarming$components$nav$MenuBar.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

I am trying to use these Bootstrap components from Om Next. I have not found any examples of Om Next example applications using much in the way of third party component libraries to be able to see how it all fits together...

(Om Next was in alpha at the time of writing this)

Comment: Regarding you edit, it is probably a separate question, and you would have to show some code for it (ie. what you pass to `render`). As you say, om next is alpha and you usually have to dig in a bit for yourself, or maybe join the Clojure(Script)/Om IRC/Slack channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to [`require`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require) it. From the [README](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/tree/master/react-bootstrap) :

```
(ns application.core ;; replace with your namespace of course
  (:require cljsjs.react-bootstrap))
```

*Note* : I also checked, just to be sure, that this function exists in the package, and [this is the case](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/blob/master/react-bootstrap/resources/cljsjs/react-bootstrap/common/react-bootstrap.ext.js#L41).